# Web Services in C# .NET and objects serialization - basic questions

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, serialization

I am trying to create a simple web service in .NET but my knowledge is limited on that subject.

Here is the code of this web service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebService1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    class Login
    {
        public string User;
        public string Password;
        public string Database;
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name;
        public float Price;
        public float Quanity;
    }

    public class WebOrder
    {
        public int Number;
        public int ClientID;
        public Item[] Items;
    }

    public class ExternalAPIItem
    {
        public string APIItemName;
        public float APIItemPrice;
        public float APIItemQuanity;
    }

    public class ExternalAPIOrder
    {
        public int APIOrderNumber;
        public int APIOrderClientID;
        public ExternalAPIItem[] APIOrderItems;
    }

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string MakeOrder(WebOrder Order)
        {
            Login DBLogin;
            ExternalAPIOrder APIOrder;
            DBLogin = new Login();
            DBLogin.User = "SomeUser";
            DBLogin.Password = "SomePassword";
            DBLogin.Database = "SomeDatabase";

            //try to log via external API

            //ExternalAPI.LogIn(DBLogin)   <- is this possible to log call to this method?

            APIOrder = new ExternalAPIOrder();

            //how to deserialize Order object to APIOrder object which is instance of different class?

            //ExternalAPI.MakeOrder(APIOrder)   <- is this possible to log call to this method?

            return "Order complete";
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of this web service is to receive some order from Internet and realize that order via external API on the server. It looks like this

Some website(s) - > WebService1 - > ExternalAPI - > Underying database

I have few questions:

1. Firstly I need to keep some configuration data which will be loaded at the start of web service instance. My first idea was to keep it in the XML file and deserialize that file into `Login` object. However, there is this Web.config file already bundled to the service. Is this a good place to keep such things? If so than could you show me how to (a) store my data in that fie (b) retrieve stored data from the file into `Login` object.
2. I've read few articles about serialization and I do know how to serialize some basic object to XML. But what if I would like to transfer data from one object into another? On the above example I have shown that I need to transfer data from `Order` into `APIOrder`. I know that I could assign field values one by one but is there a better method? Also, please notice that each `Order` object can have one or more Item objects inside which also should be deserialized into appropriate objects in `APIOrder` object. Probably I would have to: (1) serialize `Order` into XML, (2) transform XML, (3) deserialize XML into `APIOrder`. Could someone show me code which realizes this task?
3. Is there a possibility to log into some file an execution of given methods in the way that I could convert executed method name into string? For example: `ExternalAPI` have `LogIn` method. Can I create some method that can take as a parameter **any** method from ExternalAPI class (with method parameters) and firstly convert that method name into string and then execute that method?

I don't know if this have a meaning but I am forced to use assembly where `ExternalAPI` class is defined. So in my real WebService there won't be `ExternalAPIItem` and `ExternalAPIOrder` defined by me. They are already defined in the assembly namespace.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Don't use ASP.NET web services in 2009. Use WCF.

Comment: I concur with Mark.  WCF looks like it will have some real longevity, unlike previous MS technology-of-the-week efforts.  Well packaged, complete, AND *excellent* diagnostic messages when things go astray.  We recently exceeded the MaxEndPoints limit in HTTP.SYS, and the exception we got back pointed us directly to the registry key to adjust.  Go forth and do WCF!

Comment: Thansk guys. And I've just spent few days learning (ASP.NET).
However, other questions are still walid...

Comment: You have a bunch of questions here that, from a technical viewpoint, are unrelated (although related for your application).  You should break them up into separate questions.  Especially since your topics are fairly wide touching on configuration, serialization and reflection.  Oh yeah and use WCF for new service development where possible.  :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question, I would avoid getting fancy with converting Order to XML, running XSLT on that, and deserializing. Keep it simple. Have a constructor on APIOrder that accepts an Order parameter and copy over the public properties. Delegate the LineItem (or whatever) child objects to an APILineItem constructor. Easy to read, easy to maintain, easy to debug, easy to test. If you want to avoid coupling APIOrder to Order, write a converter class that does this.